# Android 4.3 as a Bluetooth LE Peripheral

Tags: android, macos, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Quick question. I can't seem to find this in the Android docs, so I don't think it is possible, but is it possible to have an Android 4.3 device (in my case, a Nexus 4) behave as a Bluetooth peripheral? I know iOS supports both peripheral and central, but it seems like Android only supports central.

I'd like to connect an Android device to a Mac using Bluetooth LE, but since OS X doesn't support peripheral mode and it looks like Android doesn't either, I might have to go with Bluetooth 2 or another communication method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way for Android devices to act as a peripheral. He can creates GATT servers, services and charachteristics but there is no way to make the advertising.

Doc: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

> The phone supports the central role;

I'm waiting for this feature too, but it seems we have to wait for next Android releases.

Comment: It seems this is going to come with the upcoming Android version 4.4.3.
This is supposed to be released next week, but the changelog has already been leaked accidentially, see [here](https://gist.github.com/archon810/1b7c6faa2e2eab831017) in line 2554: **peripheral mode (3/4): Add peripheral mode API**.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems peripheral mode will be supported only from Android L onwards. Lets hope they will back port the changes to a 4.4.x release. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/06/developer-preview-and-play-services-5.html

Comment: Note that I have an Honor 7 with Android 5.0.2 and peripheral mode is still not supported... so it also depends on your device.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, Android 4.3 does not support peripheral mode. I started a feature request on the Android Open Source Project website. If you also want to see this feature, add a comment or star the post. I think they will get around to it eventually, but it is good to let them know that this is a feature that developers are looking for.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&q=59693&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&id=59693

issue: 59693

Answer (score 1):

In API level 4, 4.1,4.2,4.3 its not possible. 
Android lollipop API version 5.0.X sdk supports peripheral mode in BLE however this feature is chipset dependent (Phones).

Answer (score 0):

android phones with Broadcom Bluetooth solution already supports it

Comment: Can you please give the source of the information or how you came to this conclusion? I couldn't find any such information. It will be useful.

Comment: you can check on Galaxy Gear

Comment: Thanks. Is there an API to access this functionality and enable the android device with Broadcom bluetooth chips to access as peripherals?

Comment: This pages states the situation is the same with the Samsung stack: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/12/15/why-android-devices-cant-act-as-ibeacons.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Nexus 5 you can install Android L there and try it, I just did it few months ago, Android L has support to act as a peripheral.