# Is it possible in Android to transmit broadcast mode in BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Is it possible in Android to transmit broadcast mode in BLE ? 
And to add my own data on the transmission.

I know that BLE has a mode of transmiting in broadcast (not to a certain UUID).
This way it has very short connection time, which is what I need.

I failed to find how to do it in Android.
Any relevant link to the API ?

Answer (score 2):

Look like the answer for android 4.3 and 4.4 is no.

Android 4.3 and 4.4 does not support BLE peripheral/broadcaster role

see
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59693
and
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58582

allow see this stackoverflow thread about the same issue

[Android 4.3 as a Bluetooth LE Peripheral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008507/android-4-3-as-a-bluetooth-le-peripheral)

Answer (score 0):

The Android 5.0.X will only allow you to use the new API for BLE. This new API comes with a new feature, which you mentioned in your question: The possibility of advertising, from your own Android device, using it in Peripheral mode. However, the disadvantaged of this new feature is that it is hardware dependent.