# Is it possible to transfer data between two BLE devices?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, data-transfer

I want to use a BLE dongle on my Mac/PC and use the serial port to send numeric data to an app that I developed on my Nexus 7.

Is this possible?

I assume they are both central so it wont work? Do I need a third BLE device?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible for sending and receiving short pieces of data known as "attributes" over a BLE link. All current Low Energy application profiles are based on GATT.

[More Details](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your Mac and your Nexus are both dual mode devices, meaning they can act as both central and peripheral. You can set your Nexus 7 as a peripheral, advertise from it, and then connect to it through your Mac which is acting as a central. Once the connection is established your Nexus 7 can host a GATT server and your Mac can perform GATT client operations to read/write data.

There is a relevant question here:-
[Is it possible to connect iOS and android device using Bluetooth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302525/is-it-possible-to-connect-ios-and-android-device-using-bluetooth/25067349#25067349)

I hope this helps.