# Bluetooth low energy network

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to create an app which can connect to a device(lets call it a gateway) which is connected to other devices. I want all the connections to go via Bluetooth low energy.

From what i reckon is that the "gateway" needs to be the master and all the other devices need to be slaves. But how about the mobile app? Can i make it a slave but still use it to connect to the "gateway".

What is the best way to create such a network? Is a mesh network possible in this case?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a peripheral(slave) role for both android and iOS apps.  The central device can connect multiple peripheral devices. (Up to 7 devices as BLE 4.0 specification, if I'm correct)

You can also use a BLE mesh network. The following answer may be informative for you, I hope.
[Is it possible to create a Bluetooth Mesh Network with iOS and Android devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57384918/is-it-possible-to-create-a-bluetooth-mesh-network-with-ios-and-android-devices)